# Application Loader Error: XML Parsing Error has occurred

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, xcode

The essence of the problem:

1. When you download the application on the AppStore through organizer, immediately after the step of forming an archive application, it throws this error.
2. The name of the application without special characters.
3. The Info.plist file hasn't special characters and spaces.

> An XML parsing error has occurred
>
> The XML File: metadata.xml in var/folders...itmsp is NOT well-formed
>
> The package: 1123619127.itmsp will NOT be uploaded

[Image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TyKC.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go find the cause of error, you have to find xml file. Click `View Log` and get full path.

[image]

Path usually starts as `var\folders\0s\...` To find **var** folder, open Finder > Go to folder, Enter `/var`. After navigating to `.itmsp` file, right click on and select `Show Package Contents`.

Open `metadata.xml` using any text editor **except** *TextEdit or xcode*, since they won't ahow any special character present in the file. They usually escape it. I used **Sublime Text**. It showed me a special unicode being attached to app version anonymously, which was causing xml to be invalid.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got control characters in Info.plist when I got into Xcode via TeamViewer. Backspace wasn't deleting anything, but it was adding ^H control characters in my bundle version field, and Xcode was accepting them. Sourcetree wasn't showing them when I reviewed diffs, even after fixing them. `plutil` said the file was OK. I used `vim` in a terminal to fix the thing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case even I wasn't able to see special characters or white spaces what help to solve the problem me was to validate manually that XML.

Comment: Where can i find that file through the finder ?

Comment: Using shortcut "cmd+shift+g" in Finder you can paste or write the file address and then open it at least the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix a similar issue by opening my target's "General" tab and deleting "336" from my build version and typing it in again.

You can clearly see where the error was when committing changes to your `info.plist` file:

[image]

> **hint**: no you can't!

Answer (score 0):

In my Info.plist file, I had placed the value 2.4.11 in key **Bundle versions string, short** and received the same error.

It appears that Apple XML validation does not accept the period character '.' in the Info.plist **Bundle version** key otherwise known as the **Build Number** in the Xcode Project view.